# Aagger2 could not generate the component file when using old Eclipse source stucture in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, dagger-2

The androidTest Code put in Project/tests/java folder is not in the Android Studio standard folder. (It's from an Eclipse project, so the folder structure is this way)

The DaggerSimpleTest_SimpleComponent could not be generated.

Dagger-compiler does not work for this？

```
---- ----------------build.gradle -----------------
sourceSets {
main {
manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
java.srcDirs = ['src']
resources.srcDirs = ['src']
aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
res.srcDirs = ['res']
assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}

androidTest.setRoot('tests')

debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
release.setRoot('build-types/release')

}

-------------------- SimpleTest.java --------------
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SimpleTest {

@Singleton
@Component( modules = {MockUserModule.class})
public interface SimpleComponent extends DemoComponent {
void inject(SimpleTest test);
}

@Before
public void setUp() {

// SimpleComponent component =
}
}

---------------------MockUserModule.java----------------
@Module
public class MockUserModule {
@Provides
@Singleton
User provideUser() {
return Mockito.mock(User.class);
}
}
```